# Position 2 divs in the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to layout my first site and I'm stuck on positioning two divs in the same line. I have posted an image below showing the layout I am trying to achieve.

[image: img]

This is the code that i have for the 2 divs at the moment.

```
    <div class="full-width">
     <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png"/>
     </div>
     <div class="social">
      <ul class="social-icons">
       <li><img src="img/facebookSS.png"/></li>
       <li><img src="img/twitter.png"/></li>
       <li><img src="img/instagramSS.png"/></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="address">
    <p>Address to go here</p>
   </div>
   </div>
```

I have been playing around with the CSS for a little while but just can't seem to get it right.

What I am looking to do is have all the above on one row, with the nav on the row underneath. Hope that makes sense. I am not using any framework like bootstrap so just using my own classes etc.

```
 * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

  body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.social {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.social li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.social li img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: how about posting the css you've played around with

Comment: Normally div's take up the whole line by default. That's how they are designed.

Comment: of course that would help wouldnt it, may fault there here you go i have added it to the original post

Comment: `display: inline-block`? Or could be done with absolute/fixed positioning for a header. There's a lot of ways you could potentially use.

Comment: thanks mate will have a look at absolute positioning as im not to familar with how it works just yet. Might try that with the logo div as thats the only 1 of the 3 divs that i need centering in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create more containers for your div's.  Here is a very basic example to explain:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three"></div>
        <div id="four"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The container class would take up the full width of the page and contain everything above your navbar.  Div one would be your logo, than div two would be another container in which you could put more divs (three and four) that take up a percentage of the height of div two.  Than inside of one of these divs, you would need put your social logos, and the address in the next one so it shows underneath.  Here is the CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

#one {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

#two {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#three {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#four {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This is just a very basic example, only to be used as a concept for your idea.  Obviously remove the cheesy background colors and modify

Comment: Thanks very much mate for that, seems to be nearly there which is perfect. Only thing is i need to have div 1 'logo' centered in the middle of the page. Will keep playing and see if i can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

I created a div with the class `.top` that has a defined width, which allows you to center anything within it with `margin:auto;`. I created a section around your social icons and floated it right. This is a better example than my previous one because here the logo is centered.

I hope this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/0sptpx0j/3/

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks for all the advice, i decided after reading about absolute positioning to go down that route. this is what i have come up with.

```
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <div class="social-list">
      <ul class="icons">
        <li><img src="img/facebookSS.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/twitterSS.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/instagramSS.png"/></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="address">
      <p>Address goes in here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.logo img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.social {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;

}

.social-list {
  width: 100%;
}

.icons {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;

}
.icons img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```